# Rotating a bitmap and transform the resulting coordinates in float format back to integer x,y values for pixel array

Tags: c, matrix, casting, rotation, pixel

I am implementing a function which gets a input pixel array containing a bitmap, rotate the bitmap by 50 degrees and writes the result into an output pixel array. The output pixel array is shown on screen. I am using a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix) to transform every pixel of the input to the output.

The function which rotates the pixels is implemented the following way:

```
void rotatePixel(int x, int y, float *new_x, float *new_y)
{
    float f_x, f_y;
    UWORD i;
    f_x = (float)x;
    f_y = (float)y;

    i = currentDegree / DEGREE_RESOLUTION - 1;
    *new_x = (f_x * cosLookup[i] - f_y * sinLookup[i]);
    *new_y = (f_x * sinLookup[i] + f_y * cosLookup[i]);
}
```

The function is invoked for every pixel of the input array. `cosLookup` and `sinLookup` are lookup tables to speed up calculation. The result for a red square looks like this:

[image]

So, the rotation in general is working but there are lots of free spots where no pixel was written to. To find out whats going wrong, I adjusted my program to mark pixels with green and blue colors, if a pixel is projected at coordinates where already a pixel resides. The result looks like this:

[image]

I assume this is because of:

- the result of my rotation matrix are pixel coordinates in float format
- the target coordinates in my output array are integers
- Simply applying `round()` leads to the problem from above: Pixels are written on the same x/y coordinate two or more times, while other coordinates in my output array remain empty

My question is: How can I resolve this issue? I think tools like gimp, Photoshop etc. rotate objects without this problem. I thought about an internal upscaling to be capable of writing the resulting pixels more precisely to their destination. Or maybe applying a filter which smooths the result after transformation?

Comment: The input to your function needs to be the `new_x` and the `new_y`, and the output needs to be a color value for that position. The corresponding `x` and `y` in the original image will not be integers. The simplest thing to do is just round `x` and `y` and pick the color at that coordinate. The next level of quality is to perform a linear interpolation of the colors around that `x` and `y` coordinate. Beyond that are a variety of filters to blend the surrounding colors.

Comment: In other words, the code is `for (y=0; y<outputRows; y++) for (x=0; x<outputCols; x++) outputImage[y][x]=pickColor(y,x,...);` where the `...` provides access to the original image pixel data, the original image size, and a transformation matrix that specifies the rotation, translation, and scaling of the image.

Comment: awesome, works much better this way :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you invert the rotation and calculate backwards

new_x, new_x -> old_x, old_y

That would resolve the rounding errors.

```
for new_pixel_coordinates:
    old_pixel_coordinates = inverse_rotate(new_pixel_coordinates)
    color = lookup_color(old_bitmap, old_pixel_coordinates)
    color_new_picture(new_bitmap, new_pixel_coordinates, color)
```